# Micronaut Kafka Listener multi topic

Tags: java, regex, apache-kafka, micronaut

I want to create a KakfaListener for several topics. All topics start with "masterdata", for example:

- masterdata.product
- masterdata.supplier

I try to implement a topic pattern but it doesn't work:

```
@KafkaListener(offsetReset = OffsetReset.EARLIEST)
    static class AnalyticsListener {

        @Topic(patterns="masterdata*")
        void updateAnalytics(String item, String topic) {
            received.add(topic);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern matches `masterdat`, `materdata`, `masetdataa`, etc. The `a*` means *zero or more `a`'s*.

Try using `masterdata\.[a-z]+`